# How to query nested property from parent entity

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, entity-relationship

Here's my scenario:

- I have a player object
- Player contains a TeamMembers IList (a player could be apart of multiple teams if he subs for another team)
- TeamMembers maps to a specific Team
- Team has a season property.

What I want: Find ALL of the seasons that are apart of a player.

`player.TeamMembers[0].Team.Season` will give me the current season. I want all possibilities since `TeamMembers.Count` could be more than one.

This is what I've tried so far and get lots of "red-highlighting" errors with the syntax.

```
var seasons = _seasonRepository.Query()
               .Where(s => s.Teams
                            .Where(t => t.TeamMembers
                                         .Where(tm => tm.Player.PlayerId == player.PlayerId)));
```

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly thanks, this linq stuff is still very new to me. Not sure why your answer doesn't exist anymore, but it worked...

Comment: he might delete his answer for not surely understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Any()` instead of your nested `Where`

```
_seasonRepository.Query()
               .Where(s => s.Teams
                            .Any(t => t.TeamMembers
                                         .Any(tm => tm.Player.PlayerId == player.PlayerId)));
```

or Dmitry's version

```
player.TeamMembers.Select(tm => tm.Team.Season).Distinct();
```